# cmake pass unique -D to subdirectory

Tags: c++, configuration, cmake, subdirectory

I am trying to set up a cmake system for a pretty big project and I got stuck at the stage of passing a unique define to the C++ compiler for all the files in each of the sub-directories in the project. What I did was:

On the top level directory in CMakeLists.txt:

```
set_property(
    DIRECTORY
    APPEND PROPERTY COMPILE_DEFINITIONS LOG_FAPP_PKG=CORE
)
```

and then

```
add_subdirectory(Modules)
```

and in the Modules subdirectory in CMakeListst.txt:

```
add_subdirectory(ModuleConfigurationProvider)
set_property(
    DIRECTORY ModuleConfigurationProvider
    APPEND PROPERTY COMPILE_DEFINITIONS LOG_FAPP_MODULE=CONFPROVIDER
)
```

but what I get in the Makefile is just the first level (ie: the LOG_FAPP_PKG) being defined and the second level (the LOG_FAPP_MODULE) is totally ignored.

I also have tried to put in CMakeLists.txt in the ModuleConfigurationProvider directory the

```
set_property(
    DIRECTORY
    APPEND PROPERTY COMPILE_DEFINITIONS LOG_FAPP_MODULE=CONFIGPROVIDER
)
```

or even the

```
add_definitions(-DLOG_FAPP_MODULE=CONFIGPROVIDER)
```

but still not working. I had printed out the defines for the current directory and they show up correctly in the directory but it seems they don't propagate to the generated makefiles.

Any idea what I'm doing wrongly?

Comment: Im having a real hard time resisting the temptation to suggest you use SCons instead :)

Comment: hm... I have "inherited" and we have just upgraded from a plain make...

Comment: @Barry: Could you perhaps give a reason why SCons would be more suitable in this case?

Comment: issue identified: the directories that contained the source files are not compiled in a separate library, they are just a collection of files. Once we will compile them against a library they will get the required defines.